# How to Align ImageButton left side and TextView Center using LinerLayout?

Tags: android, layout, textview, imagebutton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ravi.designdemo.Main4Activity">  

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navigationbar"
        android:id="@id/ll1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imb1"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout. I have an ImageView on left side and TextView on center inside LinearLayout. I am using LinearLayout Inside RelativeLayout.

Comment: just make TextView width match parent

Comment: Provide some image or sketch of your layout which you want.

Comment: you can use `android:layout_gravity` property for this purpose. play with the value by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your *LinearLayout* are oriented vertical

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

then you may set *android::gravity* parameter to *left* or *center*.

Otherwise if *ImageButton* and *TextView* are at the same level, then You don't need to use *LinearLayout* especially if it is inside *RelativeLayout* and use relative layout parameters to align *ImageView* to left and *TextView* to center of it.

For example I'll remove *LinearLayout* and do something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imb1"
            android:background="@drawable/back"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF00"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The clue of this solution is to use

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

because in *RelativeLayout* this i proper way to center views.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
add this to Textview.

Answer (score 0):

In Linear Layout child element is appears like one after one.As per your question you can do this by use of Relative Layout but in linear layout it is not possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ravi.designdemo.Main4Activity">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imb1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```